# Could I host a website under an old one?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, shared-hosting

I have a website has already hosted on EasyCgi (suppose that it's called website1).

I have to host another one (website2). So I created a folder called "website2" under the website1 root folder. then I FTP all the content of website2 to the "website2" folder.

After that, I tried to request the URL:  and nothing happen...
Just an error page display that contains:

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create separate vhost in your hosting management console - it will create separate directory & link it to separate domain name.

If it has no such feature - you are out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. But, how should I do to implement that?

Comment: The only way is to ask your hoster how to do that. It's different in all hosters.